# ArgumentOutOfRangeException after the loop which in some case works

Tags: c#

My method reads a text file and stores the information in a list. The loop ( given below ) works, and it does print the values in a loop, but after the loop ends I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException at line :

```
if(tempArray[i] + tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis] > tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)])
```

What I am doing wrong?

A part of my code :

```
List<double> tempPlotas = new List<double>();
trikampiuKiekis = tempArray.Count / 3;

for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Count; i++)
{
    if(tempArray[i] + tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis] > tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)])
    {
        int pusperimetris = tempArray[i] + tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis] + tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)];
        double plotas = Math.Sqrt(pusperimetris * (pusperimetris - tempArray[i]) * (pusperimetris - tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis]) * (pusperimetris - tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)]));
        //tempPlotas.Add(plotas);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", tempArray[i], tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis], tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)], plotas);
    }
}
```

Comment: `tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis]` or `tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)]` is probably trying to access an index that simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your `tempArray` count was 6.

```cs
trikampiuKiekis = tempArray.Count / 3; //trikampiuKiekis = 2
```

When your `for` loop gets to i = 5, the following:

```cs
if(tempArray[i] + tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis] > tempArray[i + (2 * trikampiuKiekis)])
```

Translates to:

```cs
if(tempArray[5] + tempArray[5 + 2] > tempArray[5 + (2 * 2])
```

These:

- `tempArray[5]` is okay
- `tempArray[5 + 2]` is NOT okay because you're referring to an index outside the bounds of the array.
- `tempArray[5 + (2 * 2)]` is NOT okay
- - This equates to 9, of which would be outside the bounds as well

Answer (score 1):

You write a loop iterating `i` over all the possible values of the array and then try to access `tempArray[i + trikampiuKiekis]`, this will get past the limit of the array and cause the exception.

Comment: how may I avoid that? I have 30 values and every time I need to reach... Don't know actually how to express that but like : 1, 11, 21  2, 12, 22 and so on.. @BlueTrin

Comment: Try to formulate how you got this sequence of numbers and then edit your own question.